# Вложить в ссылку элемент

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, веб-программирование, mvc

Как в **ASP.NET MVC** ссылку вложить элемент, сохраняя при этом виртуальный путь?

```
@Html.ActionLink(@ProjectName, "Index", "Home")
```

Т.е. данный метод проверит настройки маршрутизаторов и вернет валидный путь, даже если поменяется схема маршрутов, в отличие от `<a href="/Home/Index/">... </a>`

**Желаемый результат:** `<a href="/Home/Index" .... > Text <i>..</i></a>`

**Пробовал:** `<a href="@Url.Content("/Home/Index") ...">Text<i>...</i></a>` - возвращает желаемый результат, но мне кажется что это не совсем правильно.

Подскажите, как сделать правильно.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402605/create-an-actionlink-with-html-elements-in-the-link-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `@Url.Action`:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" ...>Text<i>...</i></a>
```